# Why does param object[] array become jagged if you pass an int[] array into it?

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

As I was experimenting with `params`, I noticed the MS documentation says if you pass an array of `int` as a method parameter that has a signature of `params object[] myParam`, it will become a multi-dimensional array. But I noticed if you pass an array of `objects[]` or `strings[]` it does not. This seems like it would be a headache to work with, as you have to check for multi-dim arrays.

[See MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

Example:

```
public static void UsingParams(params object[] myParam)
{
    //Code to return myParam
}

//myParam[0][0] = {1, 2}, multi-dimensional
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2};
UsingParams(myIntArray);

//myParam[0] = {"1", "2"}, single-dimensional
string[] myStrArray = {"1", "2"};
UsingParams(myStrArray);
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: That's not a multi-dimentional array.

Comment: I may be thinking in terms of PHP - enlighten me?

Comment: @Servy is correct. It's actually an array which has another array as it's first element.

Comment: Strings, Arrays and objects are objects. But Ints are not objects. I believe that this is the reason why this happens.

Comment: This is essentially why you should avoid typing arguments as object.

Comment: @TravisJ It depends on the context.  Look at a method such as `Console.WriteLine`.  It has a `params object[]` parameter that tends to not cause a lot of problems for most people.

Comment: @TravisJ, I kind of agree - this kind of flexibility could easily come back and bite you.

Comment: @Servy - That is a bad example. It doesn't cause problems with WriteLine because everything has a ToString method. You wouldn't want to extend object just to support passing a parameter typed as object so that every type had access to that method.

Comment: @TravisJ You only want to accept a parameter of a particular type when your method only ever relies on the members defined in that type.  That's obvious, and not specific to `object` in any way.

Comment: @DStanley That's a very odd situation, and to be honest you simply need to define your terms *very* carefully.  It depends on what you mean when you say that an object "is" another type.  Different definitions (each equally valid definitions depending on the context) will give you a different answer.

Comment: @TravisJ that's not why it works.  You'd have the same problem if you passed an `int[]` to `Console.WriteLine`, but no one ever does that.

Comment: @Servy - Right, obviously you would want to accept a specific type if the method relies on anything related to the parameter beyond what object offers.

Comment: @TravisJ And if he *doesn't* need any behavior beyond what's defined in `object` then using `object` is entirely fine in such a situation.

Comment: @DStanley I was referrring to your statement, "ints are most definitely objects".  Depending on what you define "is" (or "are", in the plural) to be, the statement may or may not be true.  The definition, in context, is simply not obvious.  I'm saying that the two of you are both using ambiguous language, and thus talking past each other.  To actually have a meaningful discussion on the topic you should use far more precise language.

Comment: @DStanley - The same problem? `int[]` has an inherited ToString method, it will output `System.Int32[]`,  https://dotnetfiddle.net/SDv0Cn

Comment: @TravisJ Try running `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", new int[] {1,2,3,4});`.  You'll get a run-time exception.  `.ToString()` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: [continued] to expand on that, one could say that an object of actual type, O, "is" of another type, T, if O can be implicitly converted to type T, or said another way, if O can be assigned to a variable of type T.  Of course, in the case of O being `int` and T being `object` "O is T" is true using this definition.  But to assign O to a T the actual object needs to be converted.  A new object, say O' is created, O' logically represents the same value as O, and then O' is what is actually assigned to T.  One could define "is" to mean that O can be assigned to a T, *without conversion*.

Comment: @DStanley - You didn't provide enough parameters to your formatting rule. That really does not really provide an example of int[] failing to expose .ToString.

Comment: @TravisJ I never said that `int[]` didn't expose `ToString` - my point was `Console.WriteLine` is not a bad example because no one ever passes an array of value types to it expecting it to work.  They either pass an array of objects or use the variable parameter syntax (`Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", 1,2,3,4);`   It's all about the context as Servy said.

Comment: @DStanley - It is a bad example because it still works even if you pass an array of value types. It will output the ToString of what was passed. Anything passed gets logged without an exception or side affect. If you improperly format the call, then that is a separate issue, and also a separate exception.

Comment: @TravisJ I just gave an example of passing in an array of value types and it _didn't_ work.  If I had passed in an array of 4 reference types it _would_ work. That's the whole point - `Console.WriteLine` is not a bad example because of the context - it's not the typical usage to pass in an array of values types.  I'm done - I can't even tell what we're arguing about at this point...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever you have a `params` parameter the compiler will attempt to accept an array representing all of the values for the `params` argument, if the parameter at the position in question is valid in that context.  If it's not, then it tries to treat it as one item in the array of `params` values, rather than as the whole array.  If it can't do that either then it will fail to compile.

In your second example a `string[]` can be implicitly converted to an `object[]`, so it is passed as the entire list of parameters.  This implicit conversion is valid because of array covariance.

In your first example the `int[]` cannot be implicitly converted to an `object[]` (array covariance is limited to reference types), so it is treated as one value in the array.  An `int[]` *can* be implicitly converted to `object`, so what is passed is an object array containing an `int[]` as its only item.  Note that an array with another array as an item is dramatically different from a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I see - so the only reason why `object[]` and `string[]` work is because of implicit conversion support. If I want to pass an array of integers, I can just pass them as `object[]` I suppose. I'm trying to grapple with the real-world product code consequences of this.

Comment: @user209718 If you explicitly create an `object[]` that just so happens to contain boxed integers then yes, it'll be treated as the whole list of `params` values, not just the first one.

Comment: @johnjk07 you'd want to use generics to avoid boxing in the real world. Using `object` to pass multiple data types is bad practice (though there are a few valid use cases). Generics exists to avoid boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 2):

C# is trying to figure out, when you only pass one value to a `params` argument, whether you mean for that value to be the array represented by the argument, or whether you're passing it the first argument of a larger array.

If you remove the `params` keyword, you'll see that `int[]` cannot be converted directly into an `object[]` (due to `int` being a non-reference type):

[image]

So C# figures it must just be the first of your params that you're passing in, rather than the entire array. It converts your code to this:

```
int[] myIntArray = {1, 2};
UsingParams(new object[]{myIntArray});
```

Comment: This in no way explains the difference between the two examples shown.  Additionally, the compiler will always attempt to pass a provided parameter as the entire array, not as one value in the array, if it is able to.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry, I hadn't fully fleshed that out yet. What do you think of my update?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, thanks for the test and clarification. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your method signature is taking one or more objects and consolidating them into an array called `myParam`.

If multiple objects are passed individually, such as the call `UsingParams(1, "hello", ...)`, they'll automatically be converted to the `object[]` array. This is a compiler trick / syntactic sugar.

If the object being passed is not an `object[]` array or list of individual objects, it will become the first argument of your array. In other words, if you pass an `int[]` then your `myParam` will be an array, the first element of which is an array also, making it a jagged array. This is because `int[]` is an `object` and the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out what you're doing and makes it the sole element of the `object[]` array. **There is no implicit cast from `int[]` to `object[]` and this is why it doesn't happen.**

The only time you can pass an array that will be populated as you'd expect is when that array type is `object[]`, such as `new object[] { 1, "hello", ... }` or the array type is *covariant*. In this case, a `string[]` array is covariant and can be implicitly cast to an `object[]` while an `int[]` cannot.

**In summary:**

`UsingParams(1, "hello")` = good

`UsingParams(new object[] { 1, "hello" })` = good

`UsingParams(new string[] { "hi", "hello" })` = good (due to array covariance)

`UsingParams(new int[] { 1, 2 })` = bad (no array covariance), will be a jagged array

**[Further reading on array covariance rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which also cites: "Array covariance specifically does not extend to arrays of value-types. For example, no conversion exists that permits an `int[]` to be treated as an `object[]`."**

Comment: `The only time you can pass an array that will be populated as you'd expect is when that array type is object[], such as new object[] { 1, "hello", ... }`  The OP's second example proves this to be false.

Comment: @Servy `string[]` is not `object[]`, though `string : object`

Comment: Actually, due to array covariance (and its dependence on the sue of reference types), a `string[]` *is* an `object[]`, but an `int[]` isn't.  That fact is what explains the difference in behavior of the two examples.

Comment: @Servy I guess I didn't spell that out well. I'll update the answer. Thanks!